# htaccess with two indexes for locales

Tags: reactjs, apache, .htaccess, http, mod-rewrite

I am using Reactjs client-side, and I have two indexes **index.html** and **indexAR.html** I am doing it for SEO for every language make an index.

URL example: example.com/ar/{pages}

URL example: example.com/en/{pages}

so I need to tell the HTTP server if find *ar* in URL returns **indexAR.html** if anything else returns **index.html**

```
#.htaccess

Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.html?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your htaccess rules file in following manner. make sure your htaccess rules file is present along with `ar`, `en` folders(not inside them, besides them).

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
Options -Indexes

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ar indexAR.html [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ index.html?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```